# Typescript generic index types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to have a generic function, `describeToCreate`, that depending on `type` will convert the inputted object into a different object. The supplied generic type `T` determines the type of `data` and the type of the returned object. `type` is supplied because it would be non trivial to determine the type of `data` without it.

I've included the Typescript errors I'm getting inline.

The functions:

```js
export function dataToCreate<T extends RESOURCE_TYPE>(
  type: T,
  data: IDataResources[T]
): ICreateResources[T] {
  if (type === RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE) {
    // Type Error
    // Type 'IPhoneCreate' is not assignable to type 'ICreateResources[T]'.
    //   Type 'IPhoneCreate' is not assignable to type 'IPhoneCreate & IClockCreate'.
    // Argument of type 'IDataResources[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPhoneData'.
    //   Type 'IClockData | IPhoneData' is not assignable to type 'IPhoneData'.
    return phoneDataToCreate(data);
  } else if (type === RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
    // Type Error
    // Type 'IClockCreate' is not assignable to type 'ICreateResources[T]'.
    //   Type 'IClockCreate' is not assignable to type 'IPhoneCreate & IClockCreate'.
    // Argument of type 'IDataResources[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IClockData'.
    //   Type 'IClockData | IPhoneData' is not assignable to type 'IClockData'.
    return clockDataToCreate(data);
  }
}
 
export const phoneDataToCreate = (data: IPhoneData): IPhoneCreate => {
  return {
    name: data.name,
    clockName: data.clockName,
    spec: somePhoneTransformationFunction(data),
  };
};

export const clockDataToCreate = (data: IClockData): IClockCreate => {
  return {
    name: data.name,
    unit: data.unit,
    spec: someClockTransformationFunction(data),
  };
};
```

Called like:

```js
const create = dataToCreate<RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK>(RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK, {
  name: 'name',
  unit: 1000,
  spec: { },
})
```

The models:

```js
enum RESOURCE_TYPE {
  PHONE = 'phone',
  CLOCK = 'clock',
}

interface IClockData {
  name: string;
  unit: number;
  spec: PhoneDataSpec; // object
}

interface IPhoneData {
  name: string;
  clockName: string;
  spec: PhoneDataSpec; // object
}

interface IClockCreate {
  name: string;
  unit: number;
  spec: PhoneCreateSpec; // object
}

interface IPhoneCreate {
  name: string;
  clockName: string;
  spec: PhoneCreateSpec; // object
}
 
interface IDataResources {
  [RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE]: IPhoneData;
  [RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK]: IClockData;
}
 
interface ICreateResources {
  [RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE]: IPhoneCreate;
  [RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK]: IClockCreate;
}
```

When calling `dataToCreate` it correctly infers that the object is `IClockData` and `create` is `IClockCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in TypeScript that generic type parameters (like your `T`) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to union types (like your `RESOURCE_TYPE`) do not get narrowed by [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) the way that values of non-generic union types do.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for more information.

So you *can* check a value of the concrete union type `RESOURCE_TYPE` to narrow its type:

```
declare function acceptClock(x: RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK): void;
declare function acceptPhone(x: RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE): void;
declare const rt: RESOURCE_TYPE; // union type
if (rt === RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
  acceptClock(rt); // okay
} else {
  acceptPhone(rt); // okay
}
```

(the `// okay` lines are only "okay" because of control flow narrowing), but you *cannot* do the same when the value is of a generic type that extends that union type:

```
function nope<T extends RESOURCE_TYPE>(rt: T) {
  if (rt === RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
    acceptClock(rt); // error!
  } else {
    acceptPhone(rt); // error!
  }
}
```

That's one problem.

---

Furthermore, when you have two separate union-type variables like `type` and `data` whose types are *correlated*, the compiler cannot easily keep track of such correlation.  Even if `type` and `data` were not generic, you couldn't easily check `type` and have the compiler see any implication for `data`. See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.

The closest you can get to such behavior is when you use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) type.  In this case, we can make one like this:

```
type TypeData = { [K in keyof IDataResources]: [K, IDataResources[K]] }[keyof IDataResources];
// type TypeData = [RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE, IPhoneData] | [RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK, IClockData]
```

You can see that `TypeData` is a union of two [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple): one where the first element is `RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE` and the second element is `IPhoneData`; and one where the first element is `RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK` and the second element is `IClockData`.  If you had a value `td` of type `TypeData`, you could check `td[0]` and have control flow narrowing for `td[1]`.  It's the same as what you were doing, but both `type` and `data` are packaged into a single discriminated union value:

```
function dataToCreateConcrete(...typeData: TypeData) {
  if (typeData[0] === RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE) {
    return phoneDataToCreate(typeData[1]);
  } else if (typeData[0] == RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
    return clockDataToCreate(typeData[1]);
  };
  // exhaustiveness check
  ((x: never) => { throw new Error("oops, shouldn't get here") })(typeData[0]);
}
```

(the exhaustiveness check is mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking) and prevents the compiler from thinking there are code paths that don't return a value)

So that's another problem.

---

There's no wonderful answer to either microsoft/TypeScript#13995 or microsoft/TypeScript#30581.  The easiest thing to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) for every troublesome spot in the implementation, as long as you are convinced that what you've done is safe:

```
export function dataToCreateAsserted<T extends RESOURCE_TYPE>(
  type: T,
  data: IDataResources[T]
): ICreateResources[T] {
  if (type === RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE) {
    return phoneDataToCreate(data as IPhoneData) as ICreateResources[T];
  } else if (type === RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
    return clockDataToCreate(data as IClockData) as ICreateResources[T];
  }
  // exhaustiveness check
  ((x: never) => { throw new Error("oops, shouldn't get here") })(type as never);
}
```

This works, but is a lot of `as ...`.  You can get the same loosening of strictness by using a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
export function dataToCreateOverload<T extends RESOURCE_TYPE>(
  type: T,
  data: IDataResources[T]
): ICreateResources[T];
export function dataToCreateOverload(...typeData: TypeData) {
  if (typeData[0] === RESOURCE_TYPE.PHONE) {
    return phoneDataToCreate(typeData[1]);
  } else if (typeData[0] == RESOURCE_TYPE.CLOCK) {
    return clockDataToCreate(typeData[1]);
  };
  // exhaustiveness check
  ((x: never) => { throw new Error("oops, shouldn't get here") })(typeData[0]);
}
```

Here what we've done is use the concrete discriminated-union code inside the implementation, while still exposing the generic call signature.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBASgogZQPIFUYGE4H0AqBNABTigG8AoKKAgCSQDliBeKAcgAcALAexGBYBoKUdABkk6ANJRmLAMYAbLrIDWAsgF8yZAJYgALsABOAMwCGs4FACS6RSoAipvadJCQpiMABcUAM57DXQBzAG4hMBBtPR9wCAAjIzDKXzZgWR8SKm5eR2cEVPS-AOCodTDNHX0jMwtrAmzgXJdySndPH39AkFChBSVlOg9vIq6e5IKMrJ5Gp1N8tI7i7tLyrV0DE3NLGztldENgJ0sWqDbhzuCkqAiomMgEwyuUhdIp3n3Dg3nCi+WyjTWVU2tSs9WmHyOrlaQ0WoyufRUg3aI0uQmehUyYPeByO31hJU0FXW1S21iaMGAvi4YEMFl8UKgAG14Mg0JhcIQ4AA6Gj0OAAXR8oIaTSuzMQqAw2HwRC5onEEkF1ls-VFAMqGxq2whBgpVJpdIZ4tZUo5st5DCVwvBOIMYpZkvZMu58skVpVKh1wFWZGAAA82FxDHooMYIrI9NoeFAACazHBcL0AHhwUH9BhAMfpDrZ0s5AD4ABRCPQAT1SPhwgkocecQvJlOptMpjJw-LIAEohV69U26a3+QztMYoIWy6lpIxmDnTc6ebQGB2GZQDnoaSAoJxpk0E17C7XTB2ruo0-JfJZh6Px5Yp9OJbmzS6xJIlycV8A14YNwjlDvE7bgH3WYjyEQktC0GM0nkUwDlDcNI2jcwLDYPQPWUQs-R8GcnU5OVnwkLsoAANy4bQYzCSCFBgywwxACMow3JDgBQrFAMw2B71nXCLTgQiSLIiioOoqBZB4fwoGDLDOJwogQigAB6eTrkiaNrx0EdC2DSc7xNGSnwVV8hCYlC0M0vQjwUpSuGUUxSw0U9zwZYy9FYsyLMUqBrNsgFaPo6MQC4VIUzTP0MyzDjdLzIgi0kqAcEMyhLzM7SIsdKL9JfZcoGc0zg3cpSjEMIMAEJQIc44hEoZzXLyuSPMKkrQPVMhrzi8sZmcaRXkZKRdCgZRgFLLgRysBt9WbXwlR6-gyVmXsDRbRVB3URkBqGkaxr7Sl+TCDzWpwdqmi6400sfec+Rm60clmQcAB8mWw9K8IVS60KadtfIQjcD13AD0B4WRV0ArkQevJpK0O4Chw0sHZkZAAGQdb1Sh85x4hLKAkj9103EV43-T5ANh5xGQARn5EDKBPYAzwvGHIZJxHJxRrjZVdAistXHGfz-PdidMMmKePK56r9DhTDAfxtCI0BKXpWQODSZQhELDCYmAGXDCXRh81ePQOCKgB3U5gGNuBDCKwxCwAIi4QLfBm3xuDAeQYxAFgQyCD8oEVg5raXdQOzHBmBcRkCKn9QMtM+hjY3xr0AEFfHPYNgBjYL01AcLHsfIsS3aytqzjutZuceaJoHTtuwA8v+zbaGr3alKc7RhdeM57Gv1x7d44AoDOtMekro6w9sqHntGwW3wB2PcqoCS1rkZb3D2Yx99P2-XZeb7g8x+VLeocH5Ua8niu22PIRRfFyXIxl3hk5ExWVBVtWTc17XdcyfWjZNs2LaDG2ds2AOz8M7V27tPbe19sAf2pQg6tSPrwd+PpI5BhDDHaMP0CZHCQJrRQph06pkzpmbM0l0p50oNeQuQgDz1jmqfOu7ZCI2BPuNRhYRUHR3grHLBXpcFGHwTGQsIMuT8whqkJoGMF4hwRkjKcLM9LnUXB3De3drrOF+oTYOEi4bk0pqUOe0idGMzkQop6q8VHcwPho7BBhtEj0Fvo-4lAr4SylnfOWj8lYv3YkgowH89YGy4MbXgf9LaAPto7MBbsPZQC9iGaBsDA72KaLI8OUBwK+gDGgkSYkQxbnUaYTRkJmD91MEKVikiKkNC9NIT+QguZdzfKcGExdTBcjOEXSgP4kTDAPFyHpQwul+AmKcF28hipF3+P8LJUcQyiRAOJHmvdCZdTKd2axh4Nn9FqTrBkjSNzNLOD4fpnTKrKVuG0rkNw9DDPRHceQEypnlBCEAA)

Comment: Thank you that was very much appreciated! My temporary solution was to use the `as` assertion, but your solution of creating the tuple and throwing is much more ideal. It also make mores sense why I was unable to find examples of generics taking two parameters based on each other. Thanks again!